# OAuth lib for Chrome Extensions and Salesforce API

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-extension, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I'm try to authorize to Salesforce APIs using the [Chrome Extension OAuth Library](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html), but I get the following response from Salesforce when I send a signed request using oauth.sendSignedRequest() method:

```
<response><error>LOGIN_OAUTH_INVALID_DSIG</error><message>Failed: Signature Invalid</message></response>
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my OAuth 2.0 Library for Chrome Extension that works fine with Salesforce.  Ping me if you would like to get a copy of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your oauth object here.

I bet you are using `'consumer_key': 'anonymous',
  'consumer_secret': 'anonymous',`. You need to check weather Salesforce accepts consumer key and secret as anonymous or not.

Comment: nope i am using the correct consumer_key and consumer_secret from salesforce. salesforce doesn't support anonymous/anonymous.